# Attempting to initialize a Scala created class in Java

Tags: java, scala, jvm

I'm attempting to learn Scala so I have decided to implement datastructures with it. I've begun with the Stack. I have created the following Stack class.

```
class Stack[A : Manifest]() {

  var length:Int = -1
  var data = new Array[A](100)

  /**
   * Returns the size of the Stack.
  * @return the size of the stack
  */
 def size = {length} 

  /**
   * Returns the top element of the Stack without
   * removing it.
   * @return Stacks top element (not removed)
   */
  def peek[A] = {data(length)}

  /**
   * Informs the developer if the Stack is empty.
   * @return returns true if it is empty else false.
   */
  def isEmpty = {if(length==0)true else false}

  /**
   * Pushes the specified element onto the Stack.
   * @param The element to be pushed onto the Stack
   */
  def push(i: A){
    if(length+1 == data.size) reSize
    length+=1
    data(length) = i;
  }

  /**
   * Pops the top element off of the Stack.
   * @return the pop'd element.
   */
  def pop[A] = {
    length-=1
    data(length)
  }

  /**
   * Increases the size of the Stack by 100 indexes.
   */
  private def reSize{
    val oldData = data;
    data = new Array[A](length+101)
    for(i<-0 until length)data(i)=oldData(i)
   }
}
```

I Then attempt to initialize this class in my Java class using the following

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
```

However, I'm told that the constructor doesn't exist and that I should add an argument to match Manifest. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Alexey gave you the correct explanation but it is definitely possible to create manifest in you code (you just need a `java.lang.Class` object, which you can easily create in Java).

First you should add a java-friendly factory method to the companion object of Stack:

```
object Stack {
  def ofType[T]( klass: java.lang.Class[T] ) = {
    val manifest =  new Manifest[T] {
      def erasure = klass
    }
    new Stack()(manifest)
  }
}
```

This method will generated the appropriate manifest (from a java class) and will pass it *explicitly* to the `Stack` constructor. You can then use it from Java without pain:

```
Stack<String> stack = Stack.ofType( String.class );
stack.push( "Hello" );
stack.push( "World" );

System.out.println( stack.size() );
System.out.println( stack.peek() );
```

Answer (score 9):

This happens because a context bound like `[A : Manifest]` is just a shorthand for an implicit constructor argument. So your class is "really" declared as `class Stack[A]()(implicit m: Manifest[A]) {`. So since the only way to create a `Manifest` is compiler magic (as far as I know), you can't do it from Java and can't construct a `Stack` there.

You can either change the design to avoid manifests, or create instances of `Stack` in Scala code and only use them from Java.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, but It is possible to create `Manifest` without compiler magic. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Follow up on paradigmatic answer, you can also create a constructor for your class:

```
class Stack[A](implicit m: Manifest[A]) {

def this(clazz : Class[A]) {
  this()(new Manifest[A] {
    def erasure = clazz
  })
}
```

that can be then called from Java:

```
Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>(Integer.class);
s.push(1);
System.out.println(s.peek());
```

Nevertheless, the problem will be with generic types like having stacks of stacks of strings. For this you should look into this thread: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/7267